# Selenium - Scroll and click

Tags: python, selenium

I would like to know if there is any way to scroll down and also click on buttons at the same time.
For example Instagram. When you click on account 'follow' there is a pop up with images, text, and buttons.
There is any way to scroll and mean time to do other stuff?
For example, scroll down and click on the 'Follow' button while it's scrolling down.

Now I'm just using this code `driver.execute_script("""arguments[0].scrollTo(0, arguments[0].scrollHeight); return arguments[0].scrollHeight;""", element)`
Which is good, BUT it first scrolls all the way down, and when it finishes then I can do whatever I want to. Which is not the solution I'm looking for.

Any tips guys?

**I'm using Chrome driver**

Comment: put javascript commands to click in the same "execute_script" command.  Javascript is asynchronous, webdriver is not.  (underneath it sort of is, but effectively it's synchronous.)

Comment: Should I write it on the same driver.execute? or should I create a new driver.execute that does the clicking?

Comment: the same... the driver call would be synchronous...

Comment: Alright... can you please point me to some example? I don't really know how to do it.i'll really appreciate it

Comment: Javascript click: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_click.asp